# “unter dem Namen” vs. “auf dem Namen”

Tags: preposition

> I have a reservation under the name XXX.

Which of the following translates the above to German?

> Ich habe eine Reservation unter dem Namen XXX.
>
> Ich habe eine Reservation auf dem Namen XXX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are fine, but it is *den* instead of *dem* in the second case:

> Ich habe eine Reservation unter dem Namen.
>
> Ich habe eine Reservation auf **den** Namen.

*Reservation* is fine, but the word *Reservierung* sounds better to me (used exactly the same).

And of course you could also say:

> Ich habe auf den Namen XXX reserviert.

Comment: "Reservation" is wrong (except in Switzerland). Only "Reservierung" is correct (although "Reservation" will probably be understood).